# Understanding 「あきらめたらそこで試合終了なので、最後まで頑張ります」

Tags: grammar, translation

Please look at this sentence:

> あきらめたらそこで試合終了なので、最後まで頑張ります

How should I understand it? I tried to understand the meaning, and I think it means, "if you abandon, the test will be over at once (which means that you fail at the point where you choose to give up), so you need to insist on studying hard until the last moment." Am I right? Or does it indicate another meaning?

Comment: "Game"/"Match", not "test".

Answer (score 6):

Nine times out of ten, this sentence is based on 「あきらめたら、そこで試合終了ですよ」, which is a famous line from [*SLAM DUNK*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slam_Dunk_(manga)), a manga series featuring basketball:

[image]

And the ["official" English translation](http://english-cimic.hatenablog.com/entry/2014/06/13/155154) is "When you give up, that's when the game is over."

This phrase is almost like a proverb, and used frequently at least by native Japanese speakers, even when they're doing something not related to "games".

Comment: Not sure if that is what OP wanted to know as a Japanese-learner.  You did not even mention the main clause of the sentence in question.

Comment: @l'électeur After looking at the OP's translation attempt, I'm assuming that the only thing he needs is this background information. But perhaps I should have mentioned his translation was not bad anyway.